# Posicionamiento con Bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

**Quiero saber como cambio a menor tamaño el cuadro, ya que al disminuir la pantalla deberian variar las formas, cambiar tamaño a sm o md.**

```css
  <style>
  @media(min-width:960px){
   .cabeza{background-color: red !important; 
     text-align: center;}
   .menu{background-color: pink !important;}
   .pie{background-color: skyblue !important;
    text-align:center !important;}
  }
        .cabeza{
            background-color: green;
            border: solid 1px black;
            padding:5%;
        }
        .lado{
   background-color: orange;
            border: solid 1px black;
            padding:5%
        }
        .amarillo{
            background-color: yellow;
            border: solid 1px black;
            padding:5%;
   text-align:center;
        }
        .menu{
            background-color: grey;
            border: solid 1px black;
            padding:5%;
   text-align:center;
        }
        .pie{
            background-color: greenyellow;
            border: solid 1px black;
            padding:5%;
        }
  .pie2{
   text-align:right;
  }
  .pie3{
   text-align:center;
  }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>cajas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cabeza col">header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
 <!--esconder un elemento: ponemos d-tamaño-none y d-tamaño-block lo muestra. Aparte hay q poner el tamaño cuando se muestre col-tamaño-numcolumnas -->
        <div class="lado d-none d-lg-block col-lg-3">aside</div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="amarillo col-6 col-lg">1</div>
                <div class="amarillo col-6 col-lg">2</div>
                <div class="amarillo col-6 col-lg">3</div>
                <div class="amarillo col-6 col-lg">4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="menu col">nav</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pie col-12 col-lg">pie1</div>
                <div class="pie pie2 col-12 col-lg">pie2</div>
                <div class="pie pie3 col-12 col-lg">pie3</div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A qué te refieres con cambiar las formas? Puedes mostrarnos un ejemplo del resultado deseado en una imagen por ejemplo?

Comment: Ya solucioné pero gracias wei ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en Bootstrap las medidas empiezan por el más pequeño enfocado en las pantallas de los móviles, que es el Extra Small. Para poder hacer lo que buscas, deberías enfocarte en diseñar la página como se vería en la forma más pequeña y, con col-sm podrías modificar cómo se ve la página desde sm hasta xl, te dejo un enlace a la documentación de Bootstrap donde explican como funciona el [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) que es lo que estás haciendo, en la tabla de Grid options es donde aparecen los distintos tamaños y también tienes ejemplos de código que pueden servirte como referencia.

Comment: Gracias tio me has ayudado enormemente. He aprobado.